# Express req.ip returning object

Tags: node.js, express, ip, chai

I have an express app:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({ optionsSuccessStatus: 200 }));
app.get('/api/whoami', (req, res) => {
    const ipaddress = req.ip;
    res.status(200).json({ ipaddress });
});
    
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);    
module.exports = app;
```

and a test file:

```
const chai = require('chai');

const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const chaiMatch = require('chai-match');
const { describe, it } = require('mocha');
const server = require('../../server');

const should = chai.should();
const { expect } = chai;
chai.use(chaiHttp);
chai.use(chaiMatch);

describe('/GET /api/whoami', () => {
  it('should return the IP address', (done) => {
    chai.request(server)
      .get('/api/whoami')
      .end((err, res) => {
        res.should.have.status(200);
        res.body.should.be.a('object');
        res.body.should.have.property('ipaddress');
        expect(res.body.ipaddress).should.match(/* very long regex */);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

for some reason, I keep geting `Uncaught AssertionError: expected Assertion{ __flags: { …(4) } } to match [my very long regex]`, i didn't find anyone with the same error. How can I get my true ip with express? Or what is the right way to test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is `expect(something).to.match` and not `expect(something).should.match`. See [docs](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#matchre-msg). Or, if you want to use `should`, you don't need `expect`, since the syntax for that is `something.should.match`.

The fix is therefore to change your code either as follows:

```js
expect(res.body.ipaddress).to.match(/* very long regex */);
```

...or as follows:

```js
res.body.ipaddress.should.match(/* very long regex */);
```

In the style guide, you get a good comparison between [how to use `expect`](https://www.chaijs.com/guide/styles/#expect) and [how to use `should`](https://www.chaijs.com/guide/styles/#should).

By mixing those two things, you took `expect(...)` which returns object that contains things like `to` and used it as source of your `should`, so that `should.match` check operated on the object returned by `expect(...)` and not the IP address itself.